# Using the Forever Node Module on multiple projects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, forever

I am in the process of setting up two different web application projects on my server.  I am attempting to get Node, MongoDB, and the Forever Node module set up correctly so that I can use Forever on my scripts to keep them running 24/7.

The main issue I am running into is the local vs. global installations for Node and the two modules.  I have attempted this installation process five times now using a few resources online as well as a bash script that I found here (https://github.com/punkave/stagecoach/blob/master/sc-proxy/install-node-and-mongo-on-ubuntu.bash).

Nothing I do seems to work correctly.  Either the Forever command doesn't work from my application's folder or when Forever does work, the process gets stopped immediately with a log file created.  Here is the contents of the log file:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/test/requestHandlers.js:6:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
```

So obviously I am not installing Node, MongoDB, and Forever correctly.  What is the best way to go about this process?

I am running on an Ubuntu 14.04 instance hosted on an Amazon AWS EC2 server.

Here is my require() for mongodb:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb'),
  Server = mongo.Server,
  Db = mongo.Db,
  host = "localhost";
```

Latest error log that Forever creates:

```
/var/www/html/test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:403
  if(connection && connection.serverCapabilities.hasListCollectionsCommand) {
                                            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasListCollectionsCommand' of undefined
    at Db.listCollections (/var/www/html/test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:403:49)
    at Db.createCollection (/var/www/html/test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1026:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/test/requestHandlers.js:15:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/test/indextest.js:3:23)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
```

Comment: This won't have anything to do with the script that you linked to, nor Forever.  Can you show how you're using `require()`?  I would definitely *not* install modules globally.  Forever can be installed globally because it's not something you use in your application itself.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, here's how I install Node.js:  `curl -s http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v0.10.35-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar xzf - --strip-components=1 --directory /usr/local`  Then, to install Forever:  `npm install -g forever`  If you don't want to mess with a PPA, this is simpler.

Comment: #firstComment - Not sure exactly what you are referring to.  I was taught how to do this a certain way in college and this was all working fine another server.  I ended up having to move the projects to a new one and instead of migrating everything over, I decided to start everything fresh with the newest versions.

Comment: #secondComment - And how about installing MongoDB?  Would it be the same as Forever?

Comment: Well, we don't know what you were taught in college.  Frankly, I've seen a lot of poor practices taught in college.  If you're installing your mongodb NPM module globally, that is generally a poor practice.  What you should do is `npm install --save <modulename>` so that your package.json file is updated with your list of modules.  Then when you install your application somewhere else, a simple `npm install` will install all dependencies.  Please show us your `require()` code.

Comment: MongoDB itself isn't an NPM package.  How you install it depends on your system.  Since you're using Ubuntu, a simple `sudo apt-get install mongodb` will work well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I will try it out the way you suggested.  Hopefully this will work for me.  I have spent the past few hours just on this.

Comment: Can you show us how you are using `require()` so we can provide a more specific suggestion?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure what require() you are asking about.  I used a few requires in my scripts that handle my connections to mongodb and the server connections.  Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: The error you're getting is that the mongodb module isn't found.  Somewhere you probably have something like `require('mongodb')`.  Show us that line.

Comment: Added the require() to my initial post.  If that is not enough, I can add the full file.

Comment: All you need to do then is `npm install --save mongodb` from your project's directory.

Comment: Alright so I did the following:
`curl -s http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v0.10.35-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar xzf - --strip-components=1 --directory /usr/local` 
`npm install -g forever` 
`sudo apt-get install mongodb` 
`npm install --save mongodb` (from project directory)

Now I am getting this error:

`{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version`

Comment: There would be a compilation error visible from when you installed `mongodb` with NPM.

Comment: I seem to have sorted that issue out.  Now I have a new one that I cannot find any information on. I will add it to the first post.